# Autostart and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I've this class (starts after boot of android) that executes AlarmReceiver at fixed time. I added sharedpreferences to disable and enable alarms. If I disable and re-enable alarm does not run. I need reboot emulator. Can I avoid emulator reboot? thanks!

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    CheckboxPreference = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
    cal4.set(Calendar.DATE,31);
    cal4.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER); 
    cal4.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);//year...
    cal4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);  
    cal4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);       
    cal4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);       

Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent Alarm1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, 0);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal4.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, Alarm1);
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
        <action
        android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: You **remake** the alarm when the user re-enables it.

Comment: Huh? This class cames read only when I reboot the emulator

Comment: Yeah, you *can* make code that listens for a preference change then remakes the alarm.

Comment: I already have a code that save to preferences the changes.

Comment: Show us (in code) how you cancel the Alarm when the user unticks the checkbox.

Comment: By preferences, is a boolean. I check if is correct using a toast. When I disable I see toast with value false, otherwise is true

Comment: Yeah, but you're not really handling the alarm. Just making a Toast does **nothing** to disable/enable the Alarm...

Comment: Should I need another class with onReceive static?

Comment: Before I attempt to make an answer, does the BroadcastReceiver work? Put a Log Statement/ Toast to check. And no, you cannot reboot the emulator, just close it and reopen it.

Comment: broadcast runs: when I boot emulator I see toast "true" and alarm works. Later I disable alarm, next I enable it and no alarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you're going to want to do is make a static method that makes the Alarm put it in `AutoStart`:

```
public static modifyAlarm (Context context, boolean cancel)
{
  Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
  cal4.set(Calendar.DATE,31);
  cal4.set(Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DECEMBER); 
  cal4.set(Calendar.YEAR,2012);//year...
  cal4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);  
  cal4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);       
  cal4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);       

  Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent Alarm1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, 0);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService (Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  if (cancel)
    alarmManager.cancel (Alarm1);
  else
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal4.getTimeInMillis(), DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, Alarm1);
}
```

Call it in `AutoStart`'s `onReceive()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
{
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);     
  makeAlarm (context, prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true));
}
```

Now, your Preference must be part of some `Activity`. To keep things simple, we'll take care of handling the Alarm in that Activity's `onPause()`;

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  boolean alarmEnabled = prefs.getBoolean("checkboxPref", true);
  AutoStart.modifyAlarm (this, alarmEnabled);
  super.onPause();
}
```

Now when the user cancels your Alarm or re-enables it, your code takes care of that. If you call cancel on a PendingIntent, it will cancel it if it is valid or do nothing if it is not, so we do not have to worry about checking to see if the Alarm already exists.

Comment: My situation is more complex: I've 3 alarm and an user can choose how many alarm starts. Can you tell me how write code without disable alarm and with 3 alarms? So I study a correct method to runs the code, later I'll modify with preferences. Thanks!

Comment: How to write it for many alarms: Throw in an extra parameter that specifies which alarm you're working with, then handle it from there. I'm not going to say more than that as I feel that the rest you need to try by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SharedPreferences yourPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!yourPreferences.getBoolean("prefName", false)) {
        Editor editor = yourPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        // add your logic here
        //editor.putBoolean("prefName", false);
        //editor.putInt("userId", -1);
        editor.commit();
 }
```

then use code something like this

```
userId = yourPreferences.getBoolean("userId", -1);
```

Comment: use android:name=".[sub_package_name].AutoStart" if you need that

Comment: Are you sure is a manifest problem? This class cames read only when I reboot my device.

Comment: I guess you missed the .[dot], so try this first :)

Comment: does not run :-( same problem

Comment: ok fine.. then their might be a problem with code of shared preferences.. check my updated code

Comment: Same problem. Values from sharedp are ok and also the code. I think, I need another class with onReceive but I don't how do it.